# Is it possible in an apache proxy to send two different URL patterns to a separate forward proxies

Tags: apache, proxy

I have an Apache proxy (Proxy0) which is handling the following requests for domain: somedomain:

- `https://somedomain/abc/login`
- `https://somedomain/xyz/login`

FIRST PART

I have two other forward proxies, lets call them Proxy1 and Proxy2.

I want to:

1. Send request with /abc through Proxy1
2. Send request with /xyz through Proxy2

SECOND PART

Proxy1 and Proxy2 should send the request to :
`https://differentdomain/qwerty/login`

My objective here is to be able to identify the client IP for requests with /abc and /xyz separately.

Comment: Look at RewriteCond and RewriteRule with option [P].

Comment: Are you referring to the second part where in each proxy I need to send the request to a different domain? Since for the first part, I have to change the forward proxy to which the request is going, how do you change a forward proxy for a request? (ProxyRemote is one option, but only work for a forward proxy, in my case Proxy0 is a reverse proxy)

Comment: I was able to use the ProxyRemote option to configure a forward proxy like this:  
Listen 443  
<VirtualHost *:443>  
ServerName SomeDomain.com  
ProxyPreserveHost On  
ProxyRemote * http://forward-proxy1:port1  
.  
.  
.  
</VirtualHost>  
<VirtualHost *:443>  
ServerName SomeOtherDomain.com  
ProxyPreserveHost On  
ProxyRemote * http://forward-proxy2:port2  
.  
.  
.  
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure forward proxy based on Domain using the following:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName SomeDomain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRemote * http://forward-proxy1:port1
.
.
.
</VirtualHost>
```

This should be repeatable for multiple Domains, providing separate forward proxies for different domains.